# How to use fixmyjs with EsLint?

Tags: javascript, jshint, eslint

I would like to use my eslintrc rules with fixmyjs. Is this possible?

If not is there an easy way to generate a JSHint file from my ESLint file?

I'm assuming I can specify my fixmyjs rules with a JSHint file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--fix` flag from eslint:

```
eslint --fix .
```